# Windows internet speed test

Tags: windows-8, command-line, wget

I am trying to check the internet speed from my windows 8 laptop over a period of say 24 hours. So I would like to repeatedly run a command to test the speed. Various websites (e.g. http://lifehacker.com/how-to-test-your-internet-speed-with-a-terminal-command-1364123567) suggest using the wget command to download a small file.

e.g.
`wget -O /dev/null http://speedtest.wdc01.softlayer.com/downloads/test10.zip` from within MobaXterm or the Windows Command prompt.

However, there are two issues: 1) The download speed given is ~ an order of magnitude less than various online sites (e.g. http://www.speedtest.net/)

2) I'm unable to direct the output to a file so that I can run the command repeatedly and assess the result.

The speeds from the websites seem more realistic (~10 MB/s vs 0.5 MB.s from wget) but I don't know how to run these from the command line and extract the results.

Comment: This is a nice idea. I might be able to put something together if you are still interested.

Comment: I subsequently came across some windows software which can do this. I have been testing it for a few months and it works extremely well, running quietly in the background. See this link: http://www.gmwsoftware.co.uk/

Comment: Interesting. Initially I though you wanted to just see if your bw is limited by your ISP at certain hours during the day. But if you are testing for extended periods of time it's definitely a different use case. May I ask why you want to do that?

Comment: And a 2nd question, wouldn't it be more useful to have a program, either on you computer or your router, that monitors network performance passively? That means, instead of starting speed tests periodically, it just records the throughput and latency for all your connections? That way you can be sure it won't interfere with your activities (e.g. a speed test might be a problem if it's started when you're gaming) and the data is more relevant (speed tests are very simple benchmarks that might not reflect user experience in real applications).

Answer (score -1):

Apologies for the late answer, but you can use the command-line tool available here:
https://github.com/zpeters/speedtest/releases